# Kibana: How to plot values over time?

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch, kibana-4

I am new to `ElasticSearch` and `Kibana` and my data in `ElasticSearch` looks like

```
{
  "_index": "ec",
  "_type": "monitor",
  "_id": "AU-VdlastrVNFzTbYR6U",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "lpBuildInformation": {
      "symbolicName": "t50452-2002827206.do.myshn.net",
      "buildId": "128",
      "buildNumber": "128"
    },
    "lpMemoryInformation": {
      "freeInMb": 3539,
      "totalInMb": 4978
    },
    "ecInstalledDiskInformation": {
      "usableInBytes": 387569901568,
      "freeInBytes": 387832045568,
      "totalInBytes": 499099262976
    },
    "collectedAt": "2015-09-03T23:06:44.703Z"
  },
  "fields": {
    "collectedAt": [
      1441321604703
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1441321604703
  ]
}
```

I want to plot `lpMemoryInformation.freeInMb` and `lpMemoryInformation.totalInMb` over time

What I have now is following which uses `Sum`, but I really need values over time. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your x-axis *is* time.  Maybe post an example of what you want?

Answer (score 1):

On the date histogram, each point on the graph represents a value of some function (aggregation) of all values that were collected during this time interval (in your case 30 min).

For the values such as number of bytes, using "Sum" as a function doesn't make much sense. I would suggest replacing it with "Average" if you are looking for the average value that this parameter had within these 30 min or "Min" if you are more interested at the minimum amount of free memory that was reached during this time.